# Representative choices of four out of eleven students with three majors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am majoring in philosophy and currently im taking a logic course. I am having trouble with this question and I think you all mathematicians could help me out.

There are five philosophy majors, four religion majors, and two music majors who create a club. They want to choose four individuals to represent the club at a national meeting.

1. How many ways to do this if at least one philosophy major must be selected?
2. How many ways to do this if they want to have at least one representative from each major?

Here is my work:

1. $\binom 5 1 \binom 5 4+\binom 5 1 \binom 6 3 + \binom 5 2 \binom 6 2 + \binom 5 3 \binom 6 1 + \binom 5 4 \binom 6 0$
2. $\binom 2 2 \binom 4 1 \binom 5 1 + \binom 2 1 \binom 4 2 \binom 5 1+\binom 2 1 \binom 4 1 \binom 5 2$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your work doesn't explain anything. In fact, I don't even know what that notation is supposed to mean. By $(5,1)$ do you mean $\tbinom 5 1$, which is written $\$\backslash\operatorname{tbinom}\ 5\ 1\$$ (or \binom if you want it larger)?

Comment: yes thats what i meant. sorry, this is my first time here so i dont know how to the symbols

Comment: Start by solving the problem with no restrictions. Then look at the restricted versions as "first pick the required people, then look at the problem that remains".

Comment: i did it for the first time and then i came up with that work. so im confused now...hmm

Comment: Please learn to use your shift key. Pretend that we are your colleagues, not your little brother's friends.

Comment: thank you. i appreciate it. and i understood.

Answer (score 1):

For the b),

You have to chose at least $1$ from each group. For each of the $ \displaystyle \binom{5}{1}$ choses you make in the philosophy majors, you can make $ \displaystyle \binom{4}{1}$ choses in the religion majors group and $ \displaystyle \binom{2}{1}$ choses in the music majors.
So you get,

$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}$$

Then there is $1$ left and $8$ from where to chose. So, there is $\displaystyle \binom{8}{1}$ way to chose the $1$ left.
Now multiplied all to get,

$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{1}=5\cdot4\cdot2\cdot8$$

> EDIT: since the first and the second representative, when applied, are chosen on different "times" a permutation is being made. So, the result must be divided by $2$. The final result is $160$.

Comment: This is not the answer for (b).  It should be $160$.

Comment: @Ink I can't see where is the failure of my thought.

Comment: You're double counting by multiplying by $8$, since for instance if $a$ and $d$ are both philosophy majors, you're distinguishing between $abcd$ and $dbca$.

Comment: I will update the answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a, it looks like (some explanation would make it clearer) that you are trying to multiply the number of ways to pick $m$ philosophy majors by the number of ways to pick $4-m$ others.  This is a fine approach, but the first term should not be there.  If you were just picking any four, it would be ${5 \choose 0}{6 \choose 4}$, but that is not allowed because you need a philosophy major.

b is fine.

Added:  another way to do a is to say there are ${11 \choose 4}$ ways to pick the reps if you ignore the restriction on philosophy majors.  There are ${6 \choose 4}$ ways to pick the reps with no philosophy majors, so the number of acceptable groups is  ${11 \choose 4}-{6 \choose 4}$

Comment: So B is okay. However, you are saying that a) is not correct. what should i do to arrange? or to change?

Comment: should i get rid of the first term then??

Comment: $\binom 5 1 \binom 6 3 + \binom 5 2 \binom 6 2 + \binom 5 3 \binom 6 1 + \binom 5 4 \binom 6 0$?? for a)?

Comment: am i wrong or right? any respond??

Comment: Yes you are right.You can see that the sum of the upper numbers are always the same, and the sum of the lower number are the same to.